# load default image if database connection fails

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am attempting to build a database driven site whereby images are loaded via a php script like so;

```
<img src="get_image.php?holderID=2">
```

I can get images to load from a folder outside the root directory when the database is accessible but I also want to be able to load a default image if there is a failure with making the database connection.  The DB connection is initiated form a separate php connection file mysqli_template_connect.php;

```
DEFINE('DB_USER', 'someusername');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'amnesia');
DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DB_NAME', 'template');
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

and then config.inc.php  sets some constants, one of which is for all DB connections;

```
define('MYSQL', '../../../dbconnect/mysqli_template_connect.php');
```

The get_image.php file then has a database connection conditional;

```
    require('includes/config.inc.php');
    REQUIRE(MYSQL);
    $holderID = $_GET['holderID'];

    if(!$dbc){
        $image_name = 'img/unavailable.png';
        $info = getimagesize($image_name);  
        header("Content-Type: {$info['mime']}\n");
        readfile($image_name);
    }
    else {
        $query = "SELECT imageID FROM image_holder WHERE image_holderID = $holderID ";
        $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        $number_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($number_rows == 1) {                  
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
          $imageID = $row[0];
        }
        else {
          $imageID = FALSE;
        }

        if ($imageID) {
            $query = "SELECT file_name FROM image WHERE imageID = $imageID";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
            $number_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($number_rows == 1) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
                $image_name = '../../../uploads/' . $row[0];
            }
            else {
                $image_name = 'img/unavailable.png';
            }
        }
        else {
            $image_name = 'img/unavailable.png';
        }

        $info = getimagesize($image_name);  
        header("Content-Type: {$info['mime']}\n");
        readfile($image_name);
        mysqli_close($dbc);

    }
```

If I disable the MYSQL database in XAMP, the default image unavailable.png will not load even though the header and readfile section of code is virtually the same in the section of code that does work.  I'm quite a newbie to all this so any ideas on loading the default image would be appreciated.

Comment: REQUIRE(MYSQL)?
Also, does the file exist (file_exists($image_name))?

Comment: @Mindastic REQUIRE(MYSQL) makes the DB connection.  This works as I am uploading images , writing filename to DB and then successfully loading images using the file name from the DB.  The file default image loading is the same in the section of code that works so it does exist.

Comment: Why not copy the same exact code for when the database *is* connected, and just replace the queries and whatnot with the static default value?

Comment: @TurdPile I have edited the original question to include the DB query and image transfer code that does work using the same default image file and header/readfile  combination.  As far as I can see, they are essentially the same for either outcome of the DB connection test, hence my confusion.

Comment: Have you checked to see that your image is actually a file with something like `if(is_file($image_name )) { ...etc`?

Comment: @Rasclatt The same file and header/readfile combination works in the false condition for ` if(!$dbc) `.

Comment: @thedifferenttoken When testing, are you testing via the page itself, or by a different page that uses `get_image.php` ?

Comment: @TurdPile The image loads directly onto the page as per `<img src="get_image.php?holderID=2">` . Each image element has a different holderID so that new images can be assigned to an image element via the database and I have built an interface for users to changes images and text.  This all works but I thought I should have a fall back should the database not be accessible.  I thought this would be relatively simple but I am starting to  think I should forget it.

Comment: I meant, when you are testing to see if it is working (or not), are you viewing through the webpage that has the `img` or directly through `get_image.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the database object you are using (MySQLi/PDO/etc), you can check if they connected. PDO returns a boolean that you can run against.

Since PDO is the most popular, I will provide an example of that. If you use something else, feel free to comment and I can clarify.

```
$connected = true;
if (!extension_loaded('PDO'))
{
    $connected = false;
}

if (!extension_loaded('pdo_mysql'))
{
    $connected = false;
}

try
{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db}", $user, $pass);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $connected = false;
}

if(!$connected){ /* Load default image */ }
```

Note: just make sure you use the correct image headers.

Comment: I'm quite a newbie and only working on small stuff so I have not ventured into PDO.  I use a similar connection conditional as per my get_image.php file in the php connection file and it seems to work.  In fact, I don't think it is the connection test that is the problem because when the connection is established, then all my other code works and in fact I even load the same image from the same location if there are other DB errors such as a missing file etc.

Comment: Ah sorry, I completely missed the first block which shows you using mysqli lol.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Use

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

hopefully it should work..

Comment: Thanks, the @ symbol only suppresses any connection error from being displayed.  I tried it anyway but no luck.

Comment: print what you are getting in $dbc, to check whether you are going in condition "if".

Comment: The conditional in the php connect file works, ie ` if(!$dbc) {
  trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
 }
 else {
  mysqli_set_charset($dbc, 'utf8');
 }`.  If I disable MYSQL, then I get the error messages.  Shouldn't the same test work anywhere $dbc is set? $dbc is the mysqli connection variable so I am not sure what you mean by printing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar code that do the almost the same thing.

I suspect it was the header, since I have a bit more info added to the header. No harm for you to try out.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: '. $file_content_type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_full_path));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . $file_name);
readfile($file_full_path);
```

Comment: I tried the extra headers but it still does not work.  I also tried using specific file attributes in the header since there is only one default image, eg; `header("Content-Type: image/png");`